# display youtube json feed on web page

Tags: jquery, html, json, youtube

I'm wanting to display my YouTube playlist videos in a specific way using the JSON feed that YouTube gives. But, I'm having a hard time formatting it on my webpage.  Can anyone help?

Here's the YouTube JSON feed:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/jXVuxJfLPGPP-lUw5Es--O7y4XkK7G1o?v=2&alt=json

- (I can add "c" on the end of that last url, and get a different version of that feed)
- (if I take off the "&v=2&alt=json", it's the XML version)
- (I used FeedBurner to turn it into an RSS feed as well)
  http://feeds.feedburner.com/dclatestsermons?format=rss

I have to put it in the body of the webpage, because I'm using Weebly.  I've got something similar on our page right now, it works great.  It uses a different JSON feed from another website.
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- I have to put it in the body, which is why I was leaning towards JSON -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() 
{ $.ajax(
{url: 'https://destinychurch.smartevents.com/public/events.jsonp',
dataType: 'jsonp',success: function(eventfeed) 
{var eventsforhome = "<table>";
for (i=0;i<4;i++) { 
eventsforhome += "<tr><td><a href=" + eventfeed[i].url + 
"><img src=" + eventfeed[i].logo_cropped_url + 
"></a></td></tr>"; }
eventsforhome += ("</table>"); 
$('#events').append(eventsforhome); }});});
</script>

<div id=events></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried using this same code, swapping out the feed url, swapping out the variables, and then nothing worked.

If anyone knows how to use any of these feeds to format the YouTube videos in the body of a webpage, it would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

- David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json) or an example like [this](https://gist.github.com/planetoftheweb/2367632) or [this](http://forrst.com/posts/Display_YouTube_Videos_Using_JSON_and_jQuery-7uQ). I hope this helps. Happy coding :)